# Segundo array con los numeros pares del primero

Tags: java

> Tengo que imprimir un segundo array en el que salgan solo los numeros
> pares del primer array alguien sabe como hacerlo?

```
package com.company;
       
    import java.util.Arrays;
    
    public class Main {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // write your code here
            int[] numeros = new int[15];
            int aleatorio = (int) (Math.random()*100)+50;
    
            for (int x = 0; x<numeros.length; x++)
                numeros[x] = (int) (Math.random()*100)+50;
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numeros));
    
           
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: Y qué es lo que no entiendes? Tendrás que recorrer el array, comprobar uno a uno si cada número es par y si lo es, guardarlo en otro array. ¿Lo has intentado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creas un segundo array para guardar los números pares del primer array.

```
int[] pares = new int[numeros.length];
```

Cuando vas rellenando el primer array con numeros aleatorios, compruebas si ese numero es par, si lo es, lo guardar en el array `pares` que hemos creado.

```
for (int x = 0; x < numeros.length; x++) {
    numeros[x] = (int) (Math.random() * 100) + 50;
    if (numeros[x] % 2 == 0) {
        pares[x] = numeros[x];
    }
}
```

Por ultimo lo visualizar como lo tienes hecho hasta ahora:

```
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pares));
```

O haces un bucle `for` con una condición para que no muestre los espacios del array asignados por 0:

```
for (int i = 0; i < pares.length; i++) {
    if (pares[i] != 0) {
        System.out.print(pares[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // write your code here
        int[] numeros = new int[15];
        int[] pares = new int[numeros.length];
        int aleatorio = (int) (Math.random() * 100) + 50;

        for (int x = 0; x < numeros.length; x++) {
            numeros[x] = (int) (Math.random() * 100) + 50;
            if (numeros[x] % 2 == 0) {
                pares[x] = numeros[x];
            }
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numeros));

        for (int i = 0; i < pares.length; i++) {
            if (pares[i] != 0) {
                System.out.print(pares[i] + " ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
[88, 89, 77, 149, 63, 130, 68, 130, 143, 108, 81, 97, 143, 115, 52]//Array
88 130 68 130 108 52 // Números pares de ese array
```